# Fixed point iteration does not give me expected value

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

I have this function $$x^4 + 3x - 1 = 0$$
I want to find the root inside $[0,2]$ using the Fixed point iteration. Starting from $X = 1$ and using: $x = \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1 - 3x}{x}}$
I should get the root $0.33$ but I am getting the root $-1.54$
How is that possible?

Comment: Why are you using $x = \displaystyle\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1 - 3x}{x}}$ and not $x = \dfrac1{x^3 + 3}$?

Comment: the problem ask me to use this one

Comment: I am not sure about that. See this https://mat.iitm.ac.in/home/sryedida/public_html/caimna/transcendental/iteration%20methods/fixed-point/iteration.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think you should get the root $0.33$, which is really [approximately $0.32941$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4%2B3x-1%3D0)?  The derivative of your expression is well greater than $1$ in absolute value at the root, so any error will be magnified about $-28$ times in each iteration.  The root is a repelling fixed point of your iteration.  You need to find an iteration where the derivative of the right hand side is less than $1$ in absolute value at the root.  Cube roots are good when the root is large, not so when the root is small.

If you use $x_{i+1}=\frac 13(1-x_i^4)$ you converge nicely.  Taking a high power of a number smaller than $1$ has a small derivative.

Comment: Then I got confused with the convergence criterion.

Comment: You want the absolute value of the RHS less than $1$.  The error is multiplied by about the RHS at each step.  It is a bit of an art to choose the iteration.  If you graph the function and find approximate roots you can take the derivative of your right hand side and plug in the roots.  That is what I did (using Alpha) to get the $-28$.  It helps to have a feel for what functions vary slowly.  In the case of yours, $\frac 1x$ varies quickly when $|x| \lt 1$.  The $3x$ doesn't help either.  That is the root (ha ha) of your problem.